# Inserting from one multidimensional array into another multidimensional array with a for loop in VBA

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array

Below is a 4D array (pData) in which I am trying to copy values into a new array (qData) through a for loop. It appears that I cannot access the array data outside the for loop? Take my example below, I can access any of the data generated while in iteration but I cannot access it outside the loop. Perhaps I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how multidimensional arrays work in VBA... any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub main()

    Dim i, it As Integer
    Dim pData As Variant
    Dim qData As Variant
    

    'dataset 1.
    ReDim pData(3, 23, 2, 4)
    
        pData(0, 0, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 1, 0, 0) = "2"
        pData(0, 2, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(0, 3, 0, 0) = "5"
        pData(0, 4, 0, 0) = "3"
        pData(0, 5, 0, 0) = "6"
        pData(0, 6, 0, 0) = "7"
        pData(0, 7, 0, 0) = "r"
        pData(0, 8, 0, 0) = "a"
        pData(0, 9, 0, 0) = "k"
        pData(0, 10, 0, 0) = "q"
        pData(0, 11, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(0, 12, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 13, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 14, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 15, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 16, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 17, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 18, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 19, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 20, 0, 0) = "0"
            pData(0, 20, 1, 0) = "0"
            pData(0, 20, 1, 1) = "0"
            pData(0, 20, 1, 2) = "0"
            pData(0, 20, 1, 3) = "0"
            pData(0, 20, 2, 0) = "0"
            pData(0, 20, 2, 1) = "0"
            pData(0, 20, 2, 2) = "0"
            pData(0, 20, 2, 3) = "0"
        pData(0, 21, 0, 0) = "0"
        pData(0, 22, 0, 0) = "0"

        pData(1, 0, 0, 0) = "45"
        pData(1, 1, 0, 0) = "gfg"
        pData(1, 2, 0, 0) = "sdf"
        pData(1, 3, 0, 0) = "jkl"
        pData(1, 4, 0, 0) = "fgh"
        pData(1, 5, 0, 0) = "sdf"
        pData(1, 6, 0, 0) = "vxc"
        pData(1, 7, 0, 0) = "xcx"
        pData(1, 8, 0, 0) = "ss1"
        pData(1, 9, 0, 0) = "ffg"
        pData(1, 10, 0, 0) = "asd"
        pData(1, 11, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 12, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 13, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 14, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 15, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 16, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 17, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 18, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 19, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 20, 0, 0) = "1"
            pData(1, 20, 1, 0) = "we"
            pData(1, 20, 1, 1) = "1"
            pData(1, 20, 1, 2) = "1"
            pData(1, 20, 1, 3) = "1"
            pData(1, 20, 2, 0) = "1"
            pData(1, 20, 2, 1) = "1"
            pData(1, 20, 2, 2) = "1"
            pData(1, 20, 2, 3) = "1"
        pData(1, 21, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(1, 22, 0, 0) = "1"

        pData(2, 0, 0, 0) = "sd"
        pData(2, 1, 0, 0) = "cxv"
        pData(2, 2, 0, 0) = "vbn"
        pData(2, 3, 0, 0) = "nvbn"
        pData(2, 4, 0, 0) = "bnvbn"
        pData(2, 5, 0, 0) = "nvbnvb"
        pData(2, 6, 0, 0) = "vbnv"
        pData(2, 7, 0, 0) = "vbn"
        pData(2, 8, 0, 0) = "asd1"
        pData(2, 9, 0, 0) = "as"
        pData(2, 10, 0, 0) = "fd"
        pData(2, 11, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(2, 12, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(2, 13, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(2, 14, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(2, 15, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(2, 16, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(2, 17, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(2, 18, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(2, 19, 0, 0) = "1"
            pData(2, 20, 0, 0) = "1"
            pData(2, 20, 1, 0) = "1"
            pData(2, 20, 1, 1) = "1"
            pData(2, 20, 1, 2) = "1"
            pData(2, 20, 1, 3) = "1"
            pData(2, 20, 2, 0) = "1"
            pData(2, 20, 2, 1) = "1"
            pData(2, 20, 2, 2) = "1"
            pData(2, 20, 2, 3) = "1"
        pData(2, 21, 0, 0) = "1"
        pData(2, 22, 0, 0) = "1"

    'our loop...
    Debug.Print "start loop..."
    
    For i = LBound(pData) To UBound(pData)
        
        ReDim qData(UBound(pData, 1), UBound(pData, 2), UBound(pData, 3), UBound(pData, 4))
        
        qData(i, 0, 0, 0) = pData(0, 0, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 1, 0, 0) = pData(0, 1, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 2, 0, 0) = pData(0, 2, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 3, 0, 0) = pData(0, 3, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 4, 0, 0) = pData(0, 4, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 5, 0, 0) = pData(0, 5, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 6, 0, 0) = pData(0, 6, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 7, 0, 0) = pData(0, 7, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 8, 0, 0) = pData(0, 8, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 9, 0, 0) = pData(0, 9, 0, 0)
        qData(i, 10, 0, 0) = pData(0, 10, 0, 0)
        
        
        'data seems only accessible from within loop...
        Debug.Print "  " & qData(i, 1, 0, 0)
        Debug.Print "  " & qData(i, 2, 0, 0)
        Debug.Print "  " & qData(i, 3, 0, 0)
        Debug.Print "  " & qData(i, 8, 0, 0)
        Debug.Print "  " & qData(i, 9, 0, 0)
        
        Debug.Print i
        
    Next i
    'end loop
    
    Debug.Print "print values in array:"
    
    'array is not accessible...
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(0, 1, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(0, 2, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(0, 3, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(0, 8, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(0, 9, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(1, 1, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(1, 2, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(1, 3, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(1, 8, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "  " & qData(1, 9, 0, 0)

    Debug.Print "end sub..."
    



End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, why `Redim qData` in the `For` loop each time?

Comment: Thanks Batman! lol... I suspected this was the issue. I can't believe I didn't try this before. Thanks for help.